# OpenQuery action was cancelled. Error code 800A09C5

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

Up to a couple days ago I had this very simple script running just fine;

```
Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "\\mynetwork\myconnection\mydatabase.accdb"

appAccess.DoCmd.OpenQuery "Update", acViewNormal, acEdit
Set appAccess = Nothing
```

Unfortunately now, all of a sudden, throws me an error message:

[image]

I've tried Googling some solutions but it seems that the error code 800A09C5 is rather uncommon.

The interesting part is that this other code works fine, so I'm really confused as to why I'm getting the above error.

```
SET oAcc = CREATEOBJECT("Access.Application")

oAcc.OpenCurrentDatabase "\\mynetwork\myconnection\mydatabase.accdb"

oAcc.DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "PR_NOTES", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook
(*.xls)", "\\mynetwork\OutputFiles\File_" & replace(FormatDateTime
(now,2),"/","-") & "at" & replace(FormatDateTime(now,4),":","-") &".xls", False, "",
, acExportQualityPrint
```

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: those constants you are using will default to "0" since vbScriting has no idea what the values are. acViewNormal should be a 0 without the quotes, and acView is 1

Comment: Hi Albert, can you give me an example? I'm not sure I'm following you.

Comment: When you go CreateObject, VBS script does not by magic all of a sudden create and allow use of all the Access constants like acExportQualityPrint. VBS has no idea what the value of these constants are. Turns out all 3 you used are 0 so what you have can work. Hit ctrl-g, and type in ? acExportQualityPrint to see the actual value you must use in your code. you must replace acExportQualityPrint with. So automation of outlook or word or Access does not give you use of the zillion of constants already defined in Access. believe is 0, but acExportQualityPrint is for example also zero.

Answer (score 0):

This code line of:

```
appAccess.DoCmd.OpenQuery "Update", acViewNormal, acEdit
```

will not work for several reasons. First up the code constants of acViewNomral and code constant of acEdit are NOT part of vbScript, but are constants from Access. Vb scripting  has NO idea what the value of these constants are. So you have to replace the constants with the actual values from Access. (so in the debug window in access you print out the constants by type in

```
? acViewNormal
```

And

```
? acEdit
```

Now a quick test shows above constants to be “0”, so you would replace the constants with a 0 (no quotes).

Next up your command is failing because you opening the query in EDIT mode – that mode is to edit and modify the query – not run the query.

Next up and a greater issue is when you use docmd. To execute a query, you will receive “dialog” boxes such as do you want to update all these rows yes/no – because of script and automation you will be un-able to click ok and answer yes to those prompts. You can change setwarnings, but most easy to just use the execute method.

So in the syntax of

appAccess.DoCmd.OpenQuery "Update"

should work – but then those nasty prompts such as "you are about to update xxx rows etc. will appear - and you can't answer those prompts in the script.

Better to use the execute method, and thus use

```
appAccess.currentdb.Execute "Update"
```